# Equation of the sphere that passes through 3 points and with a given radius

Tags: geometry

Write he equation of the sphere that  passes through points:
$$
A(0,3,-4)\\
B(2,2,-3)\\
P(10,1,-8)\\
r=5\cdot \sqrt{2} \rightarrow r^{2}= 50
$$

Comment: Welcome to the site ! You must understand that you will find here a lot of help provided that you show your efforts, explain what you already tried, tell where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are two such spheres.

You find the center of the sphere by solving the following three simuoltaneous equations for $(x,y,z)$:
$$
x^2 + (y - 3)^2 + (z + 4)^2 == 50\\
(x - 2)^2 + (y - 2)^2 + (z + 3)^2 == 50 \\
(x - 10)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z + 8)^2 == 50
$$
There are two solutions:
$$
(5,6,-8) \\
\left(\frac{35}{11},\frac{6}{11},-\frac{108}{11}\right)
$$

The solution your poser might have had in mind is based on the first of these:
$$
(x-5)^2+(y-6)^2+(z+8)^2 = 50
$$
The other solution, expressed with integer coefficients, is
$$
(11x-35)^2 + (11y-6)^2 + (11z+108)^2 = 6050
$$